# Installing Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) for Google Chrome creates .desktop files on my desktop, can I delete these?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, chrome, .desktop

**Context:** I've asked this question on Ask Ubuntu, but haven't gotten an answer, so I'm attempting it here.

**Ubuntu Version:** 20.04.1

I've installed several Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) using Google Chrome. It appears that Chrome creates a `.desktop` file in `~/Desktop` for each installed PWA. I imagine that the intent is for the desktop environment to render these files on the desktop like a Windows shortcut icon, but Gnome doesn't seem to do so. Instead I have text files with long hashed names cluttering up my desktop.

Can I safely delete these files to clean up my desktop? I know that Chrome installs another corresponding `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` that is slightly different than the one in `~/Desktop` in some cases, but I imagine that the `.desktop` file in `~/Desktop` is basically unnecessary.

I also imagine that the act of "installing" a PWA basically amounts to creating a `.desktop` file that launches Chrome in a certain mode, with a target website, and perhaps some cached credentials (i.e. no application is really being "installed" in the traditional sense). Therefore, I welcome any explanation giving clarity as to why Chrome would be creating these (additional) `.desktop` files in `~/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can safely delete the file on the desktop. The one in `~/.local/share/applications` should be added to your start menu. As to why it creates the entry....no idea, a decision by the Google developers. Certainly Chromebooks don't always have a start menu and even if it did, I don't know if it uses the XDG semantics.

**update**
Its also worth noting that there shouldn't be any credentials cached *in* the .desktop file - this should be in your browser cache.